# Why doesn't std::accumulate work on function static vector members?

Tags: c++

I have a non-static member function of CellSystemEvolver class, which looks like that:

```
std::vector<float> CellSystemEvolver::getProlDeathMigSumProbabilitiesForCellType(Cell2D::Type cellType) const
{// TODO: Make sure to change it, if the evolver could be reinitialized.
    static std::vector<float> tumorProbs = {_tumorProliferationProbability,
                                            _tumorDeathProbability,
                                            _tumorMigrationProbability};

    static std::vector<float> immuneProbs = {_immuneProliferationProbability,
                                             _immuneDeathProbability,
                                             _immuneMigrationProbability};

    static bool probSumsCalculated = false;
    if (!probSumsCalculated )
    {
        //TODO: IMPORTANT - What the heck is wrong here?! std::accumulate() always returns 0!
        static const float tumorProbSum = std::accumulate(tumorProbs.begin(), tumorProbs.end(), 0);
//        static const float tumorProbSum = tumorProbs[0] + tumorProbs[1] + tumorProbs[2];
        if (tumorProbSum != 1)
        {
            logCoutAndLogFileStream(" ### WARNING MathPathCore: tumor action probabilities sum is not 1.0, but " + std::to_string(tumorProbSum) + "\n");
        }
        tumorProbs.push_back(tumorProbSum);

        //TODO: IMPORTANT - What the heck is wrong here?! std::accumulate() always returns 0!
        static const float immuneProbSum = std::accumulate(immuneProbs.begin(), immuneProbs.end(), 0);
//        static const float immuneProbSum = immuneProbs[0] + immuneProbs[1] + immuneProbs[2];
        if (immuneProbSum != 1)
        {
            logCoutAndLogFileStream(" ### WARNING MathPathCore: immune action probabilities sum is not 1.0, but " + std::to_string(immuneProbSum) + "\n");
        }
        immuneProbs.push_back(immuneProbSum);
        probSumsCalculated = true;
    }

    switch(cellType)
    {
        case Cell2D::Tumor:
        return tumorProbs;
        case Cell2D::Immune:
        return immuneProbs;
    default:
        // Necrosis and fibrosis don't do anything. Should not get here!
        assert(false);
    }

    return std::vector<float>();
}
```

The "TODO's" comments here tell the truth, which is strange for me: **std::accumulate() always returns 0, although (believe me) it is never 0, when using simple sums (as commented out below)**. In case of doubts: at the point, when the function is used, the CellSystemEvolver member variables (marked with '_' prefix are all initialized and all are positive non-zero floats.)

The code is compiled with gcc version 10.2.0 (Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project) 64 bits on Windows 10 with C++20 flag.

(NOTE: I know, I should not compare floats with ==, the question is not related to it. Any comments regarding code style etc. other than that are appreciated though.)

Comment: `std::accumulate(tumorProbs.begin(), tumorProbs.end(), 0);` -> `std::accumulate(tumorProbs.begin(), tumorProbs.end(), 0.0f);` type of `0` is `int`, you want float or double.

Comment: Great! That should be it :) Lemme check... YES. Solved :) Template matching was matching against the init value type, not against the vector component type. THANKS! Would You like to post an answer or You would like me to do it?